# Как вызвать bat файл перед наполнением инсталлятора?

Tags: bat, inno-setup

Мне нужно, чтобы файлы, помещающиеся в инсталлятор, сначала упаковывались upx'ом. Для этого у меня есть .\upx.bat. Что нужно сделать, чтобы перед помещением файлов в инсталлятор вызывался этот bat?

Answer (score 5):

Тут может быть, как минимум, 2 пути:

1. Написать еще один BAT-файл, который бы сначала вызывал ваш `upx.bat`, а затем бы вызывал InnoSetup с скриптом сборки инсталлятора, например, написав в этом BAT-файле так: `C:\Path_to_InnoSetup\compil32 /cc "c:\isetup\my installer scips\my script.iss"`
   О параметрах командной строки компилятора можно почитать [тут](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=compilercmdline).
2. Использовать вызов BAT-файла `upx.bat` из Inno Setup непосредственно перед сборкой инсталлятора (полагаю, для вас это наиболее удобный вариант).
   Реализуется этот способ написанием в вашем скрипте команды препроцессора [Exec()](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=exec), например, так: `#expr Exec("c:\upx.bat")`. В этом случае компилятор InnoSetup выполнит ваш BAT-файл, а на время его выполнения приостановит процесс компиляции.

Comment: С первым решением всё понятно. Второе у меня не работает. Я добавляю эту строку в начало файла, где её надо разместить?

Comment: В файле скрипта, разумеется, вот как пример: `#expr  Exec(AddBackslash(CompilerPath) + "Compil32.exe", """" + AddBackslash(SourcePath) + "Preprocessed.iss""")`. А какой у вас результат?

Comment: Вот еще пример как раз архивации файлов до начала компиляции, но там не UPX и без BAT файла, но сама команда работает: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14599702/6935496 Не могу сказать, почему у вас не срабатывает эта команда препроцессора, возможно, причина в чем-то еще.

Comment: Никакого результата не наблюдаю. Вот пример, инсталлятор собирается и запускается, но bat у меня не выполняется http://pastebin.com/mWi1gedq

Comment: А какая версия Inno? У вас точно в ней есть препроцессор? Просто вы делаете все верно вроде, и вызов `Exec()` должен быть в начале скрипта, до `[Setup]`, как у вас и сделано.

Comment: Inno Setup Compiler 5.5.9

Comment: А вы у себя мой скрипт не проверяли? Запускается bat?

Comment: Ваш - не проверял. Но обновитесь, дело в том, что в ранних версиях (и в вашей, если не ошибаюсь), нет штатно препроцессора, и его ставить нужно отдельно. Полагаю, загвоздка в этом.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47649/discussion-between-blackwitcher-and-ufx).